# typescript tsc not compiling newly created files

Tags: typescript, tsc

I'm using typescript on a project the files all compile fine with tsc, I'm using the watch flag to look for changes. The issue I'm having is that when I create a new file tsc does not pick up the new file I have to quit the tsc process and restart it. Is this standard it seems really odd that such a great tool would lack a basic feature like this. Anyone know a work around so I can get tsc to pick up and compile newly created files without the restart?

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "commonjs",
        "sourceMap": true,
        "target": "ES5",
        "watch": true,
        "project":"public/app/**/*.tsx",
        "outDir": "public/dist",
        "jsx": "react"
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you running `tsc`? via a `.tsconfig` file? If so, please post that in your question.

Comment: .tsconfig attached to original post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After more research it seems sadly this is the case tsc can not automatically find new files for you.

> If you’re using a wildcard like this, any new files created since
>   running the tsc command won’t get compiled, you need to stop the
>   watcher and start again.
>   http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/getting-started-typescript
>
> Note that whenever we create a new file, we will need to restart the
>   tsc process for it to pick up the new file.
>   http://commandercoriander.net/blog/2015/05/25/expanding-on-the-angular-2-quickstart/

Answer (score 3):

Following the last reply from this issue https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/4553 I changed my tsconfig.json 

`"include": ["/**/*"]`

to

`"include": ["**/*"]`

and it works for now.

Will update my answer if this proves wrong.

Comment: Whenever I created a new file I'd get "no tsconfig" in the bottom of VS code and therefore getting no autocomplete related to those files, very annoying! This has worked for me. For now...